# Determing the solutions of $f(x)-x=0$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a periodic function with period $k>0$. Assume that $f$ is increasing on $(0,k)$ and $\lim_{x\to k^-} f(x)=\infty$. Consider the equation $$\tag{1}f(x)-x=0$$

Equation $(1)$ has a sequence of solutions $x_i$ with $i=1,2,...$ which can be ordered increasing. Suppose that we can find $x_1\in (0,k)$ by some method.

Is it possible to describe the other solutions in terms of $x_1$? or at least approximate the other solutions by knowing $x_1$?

Thank you

Comment: You really shouldn't use the same symbol for two purposes.  If $k$ is the period, use $i$ or $n$ or something like that to index the sequence of solutions.  Anyway, the answer is no, the most you can say is that $x_{i+1}\gt x_i+k \gt x_1+ik$.  (Also, this assumes that $f(0)\ne nk$ for any positive integer $n$, as that would introduce an extra $x_i$ in the ordered list of solutions.)

Comment: Thank for your comment @BarryCipra, I have edited the quetion. How can you be so sure that the answer is no?

Comment: No matter what $x_1$ is, the solutions will get closer and closer to $ik$ as $i \rightarrow \infty$, since that's where the line $y=x$ crosses the vertical asymptotes of $f$.  This assumes one solution per period, otherwise the indexing will be off (but you will still see solutions close to $nk$ for all large $n$).